# Simple python web browser returning: <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Tags: python, html, sockets

This is the code:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('google.com', 80))
print(mysock)
cmd = 'GET http://data.py4e.org/romeo.txt http:/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close
```

It is supposed to create a simple python web browser, but it is not working. It was copied directly out of an instructional video. The complete return from it is this:

```
"D:\Tools\Coding\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\bin\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Tools/Coding/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3/bin/pythonProject2/NP.py"
<socket.socket fd=360, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.0.0.216', 54333), raddr=('142.250.217.78', 80)>
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Fri, 28 Jan 2022 01:28:58 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:
180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:u
rl(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=
logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The video: https://youtu.be/zjyT9DaAjx4

Comment: *"The video: youtu.be/zjyT9DaAjx4"* - Unfortunately the information provided in this video are partially wrong. On top of that you made some additional wrong things which were actually correct in the video.

Comment: I realize I connected to google.com. That was embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is correct. What you do has some similarities to a HTTP request but isn't actually one. There are actually many things wrong with it.

```
mysock.connect(('google.com', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.py4e.org/romeo.txt http:/1.0\n\n'.encode()
```

The request should be

```
 GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: data.py4e.org\r\n\r\n
```

Note the added Host header, the different line ends, the different specification of the protocol, the different path (path only not full URL). Apart from that the request must be send to the actual server for the domain (`data.py4e.org`) and not to `google.com`.

Note that HTTP is a more complex protocol than it looks like. Therefore I  recommend to use established libraries like requests instead. If you really want to implement everything by your own please don't guess the protocol as you currently do, but study the actual standard. That's what standards are for. At the minimum study the [wikipedia article about HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP/1.1_request_messages) which provides already lots more information than you currently have.

Comment: Thank you, I used the code you posted in place of the stuff the guy in the video used, and it worked. I'll try to make sense of the Wikipedia article lol